# Easiest way to see that $\mathcal{C}$ is cocomplete?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category that has all coproducts and coequalizers. My question is, what is the easiest way to see that $\mathcal{C}$ is cocomplete?

Comment: If you believe that if a category $\mathcal{C}$ has equalizers and products, then it has all (small) limits, then the statement s true by duality.

Comment: This is proved in any introductory book on category theory, for example _Categories for the Working Mathematician_ Section V.2. The construction is pretty simple and will be the same in any source you look at. Have you looked at this proof?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is essentially only one proof for this, which can be found in every book on category theory; it can be actually done as an exercise. The OP should specify what he/she is looking for.

Comment: (It's like asking: What is the easiest way to show that the product of two abelian groups is abelian.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the initial comments on the question make clear, the first response to the question is "It's a one-line proof by duality!".

For the result that a category that has all coproducts and coequalizers is cocomplete is of course an immediate corollary by duality of the standard result that a category that has all products and  equalizers is complete.

So is the question *really* about is what is the easiest way to prove *either* the standard result or its dual? Again, as the comments make clear,  essentially the same line of proof of the standard result crops up in many texts.

But if you are finding presentations of it in standard texts too quick, you could try the slow-motion, three-stage, version in Ch. 14 of [these online notes](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/CategoryTheoryNotes_v7.pdf).